# how to add x=y line to scatterplot matrix?

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot, r-car

I would like to add an x=y-line to the scatterplots of a scatterplotmatrix like the one below:
[image: example spm]

Does anyone know a function which is able to do this with an easy option?
so far I tried pairs and here scatterplotMatrix from car-package and couldn´t find such an option as well as no similar question here in the forum.
I hope you can see the problem without reproducible data...
Thanks a lot!

PS: I know how to create such a plot manually one part-plot after the other - it just would be nice to omit the work and do it with one option. Please, I don´t want to waste your time with explaining such solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Trend-lines-on-a-scatterplot-matrix-td830320.html#none), the following code should work, by replacing iris with your data set.

```
pairs(iris, panel= function(x,y,...){ 
        points(x,y); 
        abline(a=0, b=1)})
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `GGally` package together with `ggplot2`. See the last example in `ggpairs`.

So you could go and add your layers to individual plots by simply adding `geom_line(aes(x = ..y..))`. (`..y..`), let you reference the y field internally -- a nescessary technicality)

```
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)
GGally::ggpairs(data = cars, diag = T)
custom_car <- ggpairs(mtcars[, c("mpg", "wt", "cyl")])

## prints all plot pairs
custom_car
## a plot at specific cell
custom_car[3, 1]
custom_car[3, 1] + geom_line(aes(x = ..y..))
custom_car[3, 1] + geom_line(aes(y = ..x..))

# or do you mean a single vertical line ?
custom_car[3, 1] + geom_vline(xintercept = 20, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```